# Jasper Bar Chart Label Truncation

Tags: jasper-reports, ireport, jfreechart

I created a stacked bar chart in iReport.  Some of the labels under each bar are truncated after an random number of characters are displayed.  Some labels Have one letter "O..." others have 6 "Safet...". others have all characters "Finance".

Is there a property in iReport I can set to display the whole label under each bar?  Similar to the "Stretch With Overflow" that other text elements have?

I get the same behavior in iReport 4.5.1 and 4.7.

Here is the XML for that particular chart.

```
<stackedBarChart>
                <chart>
                    <reportElement x="0" y="26" width="555" height="257"/>
                    <chartTitle/>
                    <chartSubtitle/>
                    <chartLegend position="Bottom"/>
                </chart>
                <categoryDataset>
                    <dataset>
                        <incrementWhenExpression><![CDATA[$F{Percentage}<100]]></incrementWhenExpression>
                        <datasetRun subDataset="dsSectionChart">
                            <datasetParameter name="C_ID">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{C_ID}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="L_STR">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{L_STR}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="START_DATE">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{START_DATE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                            <datasetParameter name="END_DATE">
                                <datasetParameterExpression><![CDATA[$P{END_DATE}]]></datasetParameterExpression>
                            </datasetParameter>
                        </datasetRun>
                    </dataset>
                    <categorySeries>
                        <seriesExpression><![CDATA[$V{PRIORITY_STR}]]></seriesExpression>
                        <categoryExpression><![CDATA[$F{sectionName}]]></categoryExpression>
                        <valueExpression><![CDATA[$V{R_COUNT}]]></valueExpression>
                        <labelExpression><![CDATA[$F{sectionName}]]></labelExpression>
                    </categorySeries>
                </categoryDataset>
                <barPlot isShowLabels="false" isShowTickMarks="true">
                    <plot labelRotation="0.0">
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="0" color="#10253F"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="1" color="#558ED5"/>
                        <seriesColor seriesOrder="2" color="#C6D9F1"/>
                    </plot>
                    <itemLabel/>
                </barPlot>
            </stackedBarChart>
```

Comment: Can you please post an example snippet? Which version of iReport are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In short, no: there's no simple property you can set to ensure that the entire label gets shown. For the most part this is really a JFreeChart question rather than a JasperReports question, since it's JFreeChart which renders the chart image.

Often the simplest solution is to rotate the labels. This gives them more room. Try them at 45 or 90 degrees to see if that's an acceptable solution.

It's also possible to write a chart customizer to control the behavior more precisely. I wrote an article a while back about [chart customizers](http://mdahlman.wordpress.com/2011/04/17/chart-customizers-2/) where I cover exactly the example of handling longer labels in bar charts. It might be useful for you.

Comment: I wrote a customizer that set the Max Lines: categoryPlot.getDomainAxis().setMaximumCategoryLabelLines(3);

Comment: @user119179 : Can you explain me how did you write a customizer class? i have a similar kind of requirement.

Comment: @Sharad It's been a while and I don't have the original code.

Comment: @Sharad, the link in the answer includes downloadable code for a chart customizer. What are you looking for beyond that?

Answer (score 2):

I am new to stack overflow. I did try few options to print the whole labels(labels fully) in the category axis of the chart in ireport.I succedded with the below option.

Please make use of the "**category axis tick label rotation**" parameter in the propery of the chart. Give some rotation value, please note that value is given in angles.The jrxml would be as follows.

`<categoryAxisFormat labelRotation="45.0"></categoryAxisFormat>`

Answer (score 1):

In Jaspersoft Studio right click on the chart and **Show Properities** -> click **Chartplot** tab in Properties window ->open **Category Axis Tick Label Font** property -> enter your rotation degree in **Category Axis TickLabel Rotation** inputtext.

Comment: I change the rotation to 45 degrees and it works. This should be mark as answer. The easiest workaround  and good result.